# jQuery slide div

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I like the slide jQuery effect, when you [move a cursor on some of products](https://www.decide.com/)

I am trying to do the same effect with the similar functionality with one difference - when I move a cursor on the box, I wanna display the new DIV with informations (that's working me), but I would like to display it as a slide from bottom to top, exactly as is on the link address.

```
$('div.box_data').hover( function() {
  $(this).find('div.box_data_info').toggle();
});
```

How could I add the slide effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at http://jsfiddle.net/ePSdq/

html.

```
<div class="box_data">
    <div class="box_data_info">
        <p> Loren ipsum....</p>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

css

```
.box_data{
 position:relative;
 height:200px;
 background-color:Red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box_data_info{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-100px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
}​
```

js.

```
$(function(){$('div.box_data').hover( function() {
      $(this).find('div.box_data_info').stop().animate({bottom:0},500);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('div.box_data_info').stop().animate({bottom: -100}, 200);
    });
});
```

​

Comment: i wonder if you need a different event listener? like mouseout or sth. like that?

Comment: @Jurudocs `.hover()` takes two argument, in and out event handlers

Comment: @NiftyDude is correct. hover event takes to attribute. First for mouseenter, second for mouseout

Comment: hmmm... I still can't help myself, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. When I switch `slideUp()` to `slideDown()` and `slideDown()` for `slideUp()`, I get closer effect I want, but the animation goes from the top to bottom, and I would need the opposite - from the bottom to top